# On Loopback, how to programmatically add data to the posted content, such as UserID and Date?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Suppose that you created an App that allow registered users to POST content to the Database (MySQL) through the Loopback API. Now, how would you intercept the posted content to fill out some of the fields, such as:
- The UserID, based on the Access Token?
- The current Date/Time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a remote hook will be right way. Here is an example of remote hook that will add created date, modified date and userId before saving the record. The created date and ownerId will be set only if it's a new record and set the modified date on update calls.

**common/models/model.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Model) {
    // Set dates and userId before saving the model
    Model.observe('before save', function setAutoData(context, next) {
        if (context.instance) {
            if(context.isNewInstance) {
                context.instance.created = Date.now();
                context.instance.ownerId = context.options.accessToken.userId;
            }
            context.instance.modified = Date.now();
        }
        next();
    });    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the data coming from client using [remote hooks](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html)

For example :

```
Model.CustomCreate = function(data, cb){
  Mode.create(data, cb);
};

Model.beforeRemote('CustomCreate', function(ctx, instance, next){
  ctx.args.data.changeDate = new Date();
  var token = ctx.req.headers.token; // or however you set that
  app.models.User.findByToken(token, function(err, account){
    if(err) return next(err);
    ctx.args.data.userId = account.id;
    next();
  });      
});
```

I've considered in above that token in saved in your way in request header.

Comment: Hi Ebrahim, thank you! I am very new to Loopback. To follow your instruction, I should create a JS file with the name of my model (let's say article) and put it inside the folder common/models/article.js? After that I add your code into the file, surrounded by the module.exports, and then I replace the word Model from your code with my model name, correct? Also, how would you get the UserID based on the Access Token?

Comment: @FabioNolasco Hi Fabio. NP. It's better to create models in the own way. You can create model by a command `lb model`. Please follow [this instruction](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Getting-started-with-LoopBack.html)

Comment: Yes, that's right. What about the user id How to get it there, in that moment, based on the provided Access Token from http header?